# Question about finding an application for a task on topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm starting to learn radio -- from the days of "Radio Rangers" and crystal sets, and vacuum tubes (valves, if you're British) -- and I'm looking for software to draw circuit diagrams.  I specifically need it to have circuit symbols for tubes, as well as the usual inductors/capcitors/resistors etc.

I recall, however, that this kind of "product recommendation" question seems to be off topic for most of Stack Exchange.  Would the specificity of needing to include, or be able to add, symbols for tubes make this narrow enough, or would it still be a "shopping question"?

Comment: This sounds more like a [software recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) question if you're after general software recommendations.

Comment: Software recommendations are on topic here. You may be thinking of hardware shopping recommendations, which are not.

Comment: @ThomasWard It's specific to Ubuntu, because every computer I own runs on Ubuntu.